# Selecting nested Li elements

Tags: html, css, nested, html-lists

What am I doing wrong here I can't seem to target the nested list elements. I tried using a class called 'second-level' on the 2nd level of the unordered list, but it won't seem to work.  Here's the bit of code that I want to effect my nested li elements: `.second-level li {  background-color: #cf1a2b; display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0; }` and    Here's my code: **HTML CODE**

```
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <ul class="top-level">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="second-level">
              <li id='brand'>Ze<span>bra</span></li>
              <li><img src="img/tie.png" alt="tie"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Asics shoes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nike air free</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sports Jerseys</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nike Air Max</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nike Shox shoes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nike AF1 shoes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Asics shoes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Nike air free</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li id="cart"><a href="#"><img src="img/cart.png" alt="Cart"><p>$35.00</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end of col-sm-8 -->
  </div><!-- end of row -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
 /****************** HEADER **********************/


    .top-level { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; }

    .top-level > li { height: auto; padding: 15px 0; display: inline-block; position: relative; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Helevitca Neue'; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; width: 149px; background: #fff; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;  -moz-transition: all 0.2s; -ms-transition: all 0.2s; -o-transition: all 0.2s; transition: all 0.2s; }

    .top-level > li:hover  { background-color: #cf1a2b; }

    .top-level a { color: #626262;  }

    .header li:hover a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }

    #cart p { display: inline; }

    .top-level li > ul  { background: #cf1a2b; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; width: 100%; padding: 0; list-style-type: none;  }



    .second-level li {  background-color: #cf1a2b; display: block; margin: 0; text-align: center; padding: 10px 0; }

    li#brand { font-family: 'Helevitca Neue'; font-size: 38px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; border: 1px solid #fff; border-left: none; }

    #brand span { color: #fec8cd; }
```

[image: No effect from css code on nested li elements]

Comment: We don't need your entire document, nor all the commented out stuff. Please simplify to just what's relevant--a list and your CSS rule.

Comment: See [mcve]  /......

Comment: Your `.second-level li {}` selector seems to be working just fine. What isn't working about it?

Comment: @TylerH when I view my code in the browser and inspect a li element in from nested li, the rule isn't in my styles section of the css, I'll add a picture to show you what I mean.

Comment: It works, thanks for wasting my time, I rarely downvote, but this.....
Just select them like :
.second-level li:hover{
  transform:rotate(120deg);
}

.second-level li {
  transition:1s;
}

Comment: @damianocelent thanks man sorry I wasted your time, but the problem was that I had an extra */ that was commenting out the line of code that affected the nested li elements.  Ya'll told me to delete the excess code and only post the code relevant to the problem, so I deleted after the comments.  Thank you though, I learned a cool effect too, I like that hover transform.

Comment: no problem, taki didnt downvote, such errors are kinda hard to find. I suggest to run the css code through a validator many times throughout a development, this has prevented me from losing a lot of time before:-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had an extra `*/` before the css code that affected the nested li elements, which prevented the change.

```
/*-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s; -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s; -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s; -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;  -transition: opacity 0.2s;}*/ */

.second-level li {  background-color: #cf1a2b; display: block; margin: 0; text-align: center;  padding: 20px 0; }
```